# Is there a way to remote debug a ASP.net App deployed to a virtual directory?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory

I have the need to debug an app that was deployed to a virtual directory on a azure app service.

Currentlly attaching the debugger from the cloud explorer attaches to the app in the root of the service and not the "child" app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your child app is also available in the list of processes during the time when you try attaching the debugger and is available in attach processes dialog box.

Also, please ensure that the app that you are trying to remote debug is enabled in Azure.

If your child app is not available in list of processes, please follow below instructions and see if you are missing anything.

[Remote debug your Azure App Service Web App](https://benperk.github.io/msdn/2016/2016-09-remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app.html)